# How to remove npmjs package QRcode warning

Tags: javascript, node.js, image, warnings, qr-code

here is the warning I get

```
(node:24688) ExperimentalWarning: buffer.Blob is an experimental feature. This feature could change at any time
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
```

How Do I remove this warning from appearing?

Answer (score 0):

That warning is generated from the package/dependency.
Consider reaching out to the development team for that package.

You may set the flag `NODE_OPTIONS=--no-warnings` to suppress all warnings.
However, you may want to keep this flag on for development.

You may also start your application with the `--trace-warning` option like the console state, to display the stack for this warning.